# understanding duplicates in data.table (and data.frame)

Tags: r, data.table

I am having difficulties understanding duplicated().

First, is it correct that there are duplicates in the diamonds dataset? 
Second, where do the duplicates in the melted data.table come from, given that I work with a deduplicated dataset?

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

# duplicates in data.frame
dups.df = nrow(diamonds[duplicated(diamonds),])  # 146 records
diamonds.dedup = unique(diamonds)

dt = as.data.table(diamonds.dedup)

d = melt(dt, value.var = "cut")
dups.d = d[duplicated(d),]
nrow(dups.d)  # 232821 records
```

Comment: The example is not reproducible. From which package the function `melt` is coming?

Comment: @Pascal - reshape2, I have added that in the question. Melt then uses data.table, as you can see with str(d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using a 54K row dataset would help you to pick out what is happening. E.g.:

```
test <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,2),b=c(1,1,4,4),vals1=c(2,2,3,4),vals2=3:6)
test <- test[c(1:4,4),]   # make it have a duplicated row
test <- unique(test)      # now get rid of it just to prove a point

#  a b vals1 vals2
#1 1 1     2     3
#2 1 1     2     4
#3 2 4     3     5
#4 2 4     4     6
```

Now melt this data similar to how you have done:

```
melt(id=c("a","b"),data=test)

#  a b variable value
#1 1 1    vals1     2
#2 1 1    vals1     2  ## duplicate!
#3 2 4    vals1     3
#4 2 4    vals1     4
#5 1 1    vals2     3
#6 1 1    vals2     4
#7 2 4    vals2     5
#8 2 4    vals2     6
```

Surprise, now you've got duplicates.
Where you previously were looking for whole rows that were identical across the idvars of `a/b` and `vals1/vals2`, now you only have to match the `id` variables and one `value` corresponding to `vals1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the last lines of code with the original diamonds set

```
dt <- as.data.table(diamonds)
d <- melt(dt, value.var = "cut")
dups.d <- d[duplicated(d), ]
nrow(dups.d)  # 233843 records
```

You will see that the number of duplicated records is higher (`233843` instead of `232821`) than with your deduplicated set. Think about how `duplicated` works on a melted data table!